# Require password for LXC container shell access

Tags: authentication, lxc

I'm trying to lockdown shell access to the containers I'm running. In essensse, if someone is on the LXC host computer, I would like for them to have to enter a username/password before they get shell access to the container. Mainly for the sake of logging/tracking whom did what to which container.

So far I've tried the following:

1. using `lxc console mycontainer` I get a login prompt requiring username/password. It works but `lxc shell mycontainer` etc still pop a root shell without so much as a password request.
2. if I disable the container root user (set shell to no login / disable the account) I need to use `lxc exec mycontainer -- sudo --login --user myuser` to get a shell, but it does not ask for a password.

Short of restricting the host lxc commands (eg. unless you are in the "lxc admin" group, you are only allowed to use `lxc console`) I cannot see a way of locking this down. Some form of authentication portal between the container and host machine would be good, but can't run an ssh server on every container.

Anyone got any pointers?